# How to find the System Volume?

Tags: core-audio, avaudioplayer, audio

I have an issue on an iPhone app.
I am looking at SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification and the related documentation and also browsing the net.
But I can't find a simple way to get the current value of the SystemVolume.
I cannot believe this information is impossible to get simply, but for some reason I have not been successful.

I also noticed the music application on iPod touch, does exactly what I would like to have, so it must be easy.

Anyone knows the answer?

Thank you for any relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for getting the current volume, the result output will be from 0.0 to 1.0.

```
Float32 volume;
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(Float32);

Float32 currentVolume= AudioSessionGetProperty (
                         'chov',
                         &dataSize,
                         &volume
                         );
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I must be doing something wrong. I always get the value 0.0 when I try this code. Should I be cautious about something when using it?

Comment: Finally it works. I was just looking at the wrong variable. I have to get the result in volume I expected it in currentVolume. Thanks again!